Confused how to handle dispose. Especially with DI container and constructor injection
Bit confused about IDispose.
How does IDispose tell the GC that it can remove this instance from memory?
Not totally sure what: GC.SuppressFinalize does.
In this example repositories should also be removed from the memory. How can I do that without waiting for the garbage collector to do it?
I would like Func<IUnitOfWork> injection to make the caller be responsible to dispose and when IUnitOfWork is injected then the container should be responsible in the most optimal situation. But I would at least like to use IDispose correctly in the first place.
I assume currently Autofac has one scope and that is the container scope so it will dispose all objects when the app closes so does it even matter if I dispose of it beforehand when I create it through Func<IUnitOfWork>?
Here I build the container:
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
#if DEBUG
            Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
#endif
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                }).ConfigureContainer(
                new AutofacServiceProviderFactory(containerBuilder =>
                {
                    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new Services.Bindings());
                    containerBuilder.RegisterModule(new Bindings());
                }));
#if DEBUG
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine("Time to do all create DI container: " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
            
            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

My bindings are:
            // storage EFC implementation
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EFCRepository<>))
                .AsSelf()
                .As(typeof(IReadRepository<>))
                .As(typeof(ICreateRepository<>))
                .As(typeof(IUpdateRepository<>))
                .As(typeof(IDeleteRepository<>));

            builder.RegisterType<EFCOrderRepository>().AsSelf().As<IOrderRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<EFCManualRepository>().AsSelf().As<IManualRepository>();


            builder.RegisterType<EFCOrderRepository<EFCRepository<Order>>>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<EFCManualRepository<EFCRepository<Manual>>>().AsSelf();

            builder.Register<Func<DbSet<Order>, IOrderRepository>>((context) => {
                context = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                return (set) => {
                    EFCRepository<Order> repo =
                    context.Resolve<EFCRepository<Order>>(TypedParameter.From<DbSet<Order>>(set));
                    return context.Resolve<EFCOrderRepository<EFCRepository<Order>>>(TypedParameter.From(repo));
                };
            });

            builder.Register<Func<DbSet<Manual>, IManualRepository>>((context) => {
                context = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                return (set) => {
                    EFCRepository<Manual> repo = 
                    context.Resolve<EFCRepository<Manual>>(TypedParameter.From<DbSet<Manual>>(set));
                    return context.Resolve<EFCManualRepository<EFCRepository<Manual>>>(TypedParameter.From(repo));
                };
            });

            builder.RegisterType<EFCUnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>();
             
            builder.RegisterType<SqliteAmpuleProductionContext>()
                .As<AmpuleProductionContext>().As<DbContext>();

            builder.RegisterType<EFCStorageStartup>().As<IStartup>();

Currently my Unit of work looks like this:
        public EFCUnitOfWork(Func<AmpuleProductionContext> contextFactory,
            Func<DbSet<Manual>, IManualRepository> manualRepoFactory,
            Func<DbSet<Order>, IOrderRepository> orderRepoFactory)
        {
            _disposed = false;
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
            _manualRepoFactory = manualRepoFactory;
            _orderRepoFactory = orderRepoFactory;
        }

...


        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if(_context != null)
                    {
                        _context.Dispose();
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

                ~EFCUnitOfWork()
        {
#if DEBUG
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unit of Work not disposed correctly! It got disposed at finalize instead!");
            }
#endif
            Dispose(false);

        }


Gc knows nothing about idisposable

Why are you puttin factories into autofac? Autofac should create things as needed

What's the purpose of GC.SuppressFinalize(this) in Dispose() method?

The article i read about IDispose was confusing this makes it fully clear for me. Thanks HereticMonkey. I need to put those in because if i don't it will try to set param dbset for EFCOrderRepository that does not exist instead of the EFCRepository. @DanielA.White I could just return EFCRepository instead of a facade but then it is possible to cast it and then run updates that should not be allowed.

Returning EFCRepository will also not work because it does not implement IOrderRepository or an equiv interface.

I think i get it a bit more. I should use externally owned for db context and unit of work to avoid memory leaks because the created scopes (container = scope as well) will keep a pointer towards all idispose objects otherwise. I could also use instanceperlifetime on dbcontext and either return Func<Owned> or create a scope in the unit of work itself that gets disposed in its own dispose... while making my unit of work externally owned... and then make m repos take dbcontext as constructor param so it requires no register func
